# Link resource file to multiple projects

Tags: c#, tfs

I have two projects A|B. A is a creator and B is a consumer of what A creates. Each project needs to use a global.txt file which has configurations. Each project has its own solution in TFS. Is there a way to link global.txt from a location in TFS into each project so that if someone edits the global.txt, then rebuilds project A it will contain the updated file without having to update it manually

Comment: can you clarify more how your projects are arranged? You can have a rolling build, include the global.txt file in the source settings. The team bulid will build the two projects

Comment: Are you talking about the normal project in VS or Team Project? Did the two solutions in the same Team Project?

Comment: Can you use "Add > Existing Item" and then select "Add As Link" in the drop-down button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you configure the [source repositories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/repository) in the build definitions separately for two solutions, you could both include the `global.txt` file mapping.

At the beginning of the build process, the agent downloads files from your remote repository(on TFS) into a local sources directory(build agent).

Then set a [CI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/triggers) trigger , the builds will run whenever some changes made to `global.txt` and checked in.